# Using Intel RealSense Depth Camera together with Zoom Conferencing doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, zoom-meeting

I am trying to use my Intel RealSense Depth Camera D415 (which provides an RGB stream) together with Zoom for linux.

I have sucessfully installed the kernel modules and utils using the following [link](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md). When running `realsense-viewer` I can view the RGB stream, depth stream and so on... everything works perfectly.

However when starting Zoom I do not get any video output from the settings nor in video calls. However I can choose between three video devices (which I guess are for IR, RGB and Laser).

This is what `v4l-ctl` *thinks* about my attached video devices. So from a kernel- and system point of view everything seems fine.

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices --verbose
Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Ca (usb-0000:00:14.0-4):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/video2
```

**Questions**

- Any ideas Zoom might not output any video although it seems to recognize the video devices?
- I have been searching high and low, but what command line parameters are supported by the `ZoomLauncher` binary? Using `--help | -h | -?` and so on didn't bring up anything useful.